# Firebase signin successful but unable to retrieve user info

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, angular7, ionic4

I am trying to retrieve the authenticated user info after successful firebase signin but I seem to be missing something. Here's a step by step summary of my ionic app logic

1. User clicks a button that calls the `authStatus()`method to check if the user is signed in or not in **schedules.page.ts**. If the user is not signed in, a modal is presented like this

```
authStatus() {
    // if user is not signed in, present register modal
    if (this.authService.user == null) {
        this.presentModal();
    }
    // if user is not null, do something
}

// present & dismiss modal
async presentModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
        component: RegisterModalPage
    });

    return await modal.present();
}
```

The modal displays buttons that should clicked based on a user's prefered method of signing in (gmail or facebook)

2. User clicks on button to signin with gmail account which calls the `gmailReg()` method of the **register-modal.page.ts**.

```
gmailReg() {
    this.authService.signInWithGmail();
}
```

`signInWithGmail()` method is from the **authentication.service.ts**

```
export class AuthenticateService {
  public user = null;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  signInWithGmail() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());

    this.afAuth.auth.getRedirectResult().then(result => {
      this.user = result.user;
    });
  }
}
```

In my app.component.html file, I want to display the `displayName` of the authenticated user like this

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title *ngIf="authService.user == null">Menu</ion-title>
    <ion-title *ngIf="authService.user != null">{{
    authService.user.displayName
    }}</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

and the `AuthenticateService` is imported correctly in **app.module.ts** like this

```
import { AuthenticateService } from "./auth/authenticate.service";

constructor(
    public authService: AuthenticateService,
    ...
)
```

But the user seems to remain null and not set as I intend for it to when the `signInWithGmail()` completes. What am I missing?

Comment: I tried changing the signin method in `AuthenticateService` from `signInWithRedirect` to `signInWithPopup` and I was able to set the user same way as I intended to. So does it mean that I am using the `getRedirectResult` wrongly?

Comment: Which version of Ionic are you using? Are you building a PWA or a Hybrid Mobile App? Which version of angularfire2 are you using?

Comment: @Robinyo I am building a hybrid mobile app with Ionic 4, Angular 7 with AngularFire2 v5.0

Answer (score 0):

From [firebase google sign-in doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?authuser=0) `getRedirectResult` should be called when the page loads. So I added a method to get the current user in `AuthenticateService`

```
currentUser() {
    this.afAuth.auth.getRedirectResult().then(result => {
      if (result.user) {
        this.user = result.user;
        // const token = result.credential.toJSON();
        console.log(this.user);
      }
    });
}
```

and then edited the `signInWithGmail()` method like this

```
signInWithGmail() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}
```

Now I can call the `currentUser()` method in any part of the app. One problem though is when I call the method in any page, the user object is not returned immediately and takes sometime to later. That still needs to be fixed.